# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException Javamail

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I try to send an email using javaMail version 1.5.5, I got this SMTPSendFailedException and I don't know why.

Here a part of the exception:

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error. w133sm10373661ywa.37 - gsmtp

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
```

My properties are:

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

```
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "user";

    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "false");

    props.setProperty("mail.session.mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "LOGIN");
    props.setProperty("mail.session.mail.smtp.auth.plain.disable", "false");

    props.setProperty("mail.session.mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 6000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't like your From address.  When you constructed the message, did you use the setFrom method?  What address did you supply?

It might help to see the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) showing exactly what's being sent to the server.

Also, those `mail.session.*` properties are not valid JavaMail properties.  Did you expect JavaMail to look at them or are you using them for some other purpose?

Comment: Yes, those mail.session.* are wrong , thank you, I set the From address in mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress("address"));

Comment: It looks like your server doesn't think that whatever "address" is is a valid address.  Can you post the debug output?  Or tell us more precisely what "address" actually is?

Comment: Thanks for your help, in debug output I saw a special character in from address so that was the problem, I removed this and finally I sent the email.

Comment: The special character was a little whitespace.